# Testing reactive variables in vue with vitest. Adding the $ makes it undefined in test

Tags: vue.js, vitest

I'm using vitest to add unit tests to some Vue components and I have a weird error that I'm having a hard time solving. I'm new to Vue and its auto imports and I think that is probably where the issue lies, with the auto imports. I've created some reactive variables and they make the tests complain that "$ref is not defined. When I remove the $ the tests will succeed, but they I lose the reactive behavior of those variables. Here are the variables

```
let activeURL = $ref("");
let dropdownItems = $ref([]);
```

and I am mounting the component for the test like this

```
    const wrapper = mount(LeaderboardMenu);
```

Comment: Reactive transforms are deprecated, if you're new to them and it's your decision to use them, probably this isn't the best time to start

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. Our repository uses this reactivityTransform plugin to allow us to use $ref and $computed to make reactive variables easier syntactically. Those were already in our nuxt config, I needed to add them to our vite config since that is what our tests run off of

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import AutoImport from "unplugin-auto-import/vite";
import ReactivityTransform from "@vue-macros/reactivity-transform/vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    ReactivityTransform(),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ["vue", "vue/macros"],
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "happy-dom",
  },
});
```

Comment: So did you manage to solve it?

Comment: yes! This solved the issue.